# Finding a curve C that satisfies the hypnothesis of Green's Theorem for the following function.

Tags: calculus, optimization, indefinite-integrals, greens-theorem

So, i need to find a curve $\mathcal C$, with Green's Theorem, such as(this is a line integral, but i don't know how to insert with MathJax, sorry) $$\int \left(\frac{y^{3}}{12} - y\right)dx - \left(\frac{x^{3}}{27}\right)dy$$ is maximum. I know how to evaluate integrals using Green's Theorem, but I don't know where to start on this one.

Comment: Do you need this curve to be a closed loop?

Comment: Yes! But i'm lost on where to begin, i thought about using lagrange multipliers, but that's probably wrong

Comment: Suppose you have the closed curve, bounding the region $D$. then your integral is equal to something of the type (this is just Green's formula)$$\iint_D f(x,y) dxdy$$ Now, try to choose $D$ as large as possible inside the set $\{ f(x,y) \ge 0 \}$ to maximize your integral.

Comment: could uou please elaborate more on the hint ?